# Ajax:Can't get ajax to work properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For some reason I can't get my ajax to work properly, was able to do it before. It shouldn't reload the page(which it does) on submit, which makes me think that ajax somehow isn't working. Also I tried to check for cookies in my browser, and there were no cookies that I expected there to be, so the code didn't worked to that place.

I got this code,Html:

```
<form name="signIn" id="signIn" name="signIn" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" id="login_email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="********" maxlength="20" id="login_password" />
    <input type="image" id="signInButton" onClick="login()" src="img/signIn.png" alt=">" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript login() function:

```
function login()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("login_email");
    var p = document.getElementById("login_password");
    if(e.value == "" && p.value == "")
    {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        p.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "php_includes/login.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
            {
                var return_data = ajax.responseText;
                if(return_data == "login_failed")
                {
                    e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    p.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
                else if(return_data == "login_success")
                {
                    e.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    p.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

PHP login.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["e"]))
{
    $e = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e']);
    $p = md5($_POST['p']);
    if($e == "" || $p == "")
    {
        echo "login_failed";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE email='$e' AND password='$p' AND emailactivated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($numrows < 1)
        {
            echo "login_failed";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            $sql = "UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            echo "login_success";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" id="signInButton" onClick="login()" src="img/signIn.png" alt=">" name="submit" />
```

Acts as a submit button.

either change that to `<img id="signInButton" onClick="login()" src="img/signIn.png">`

or user jquery [prevenDefault](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.preventDefault.28.29)

to prevent form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

When the form submits, it will post the form data to index.php.  The ajax is asynchronous and will not finish before the redirect happens.  You can prevent submission by getting rid of `name="submit"` or by setting the form's onsubmit attribute like so `onsubmit="return false;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX like this instead your JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#signInButton").click(function(){
        var email=$("input#login_email").val();
        var password=$("input#login_password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"login.php",
            data:{"e":email,"p":password},
            cache:false,
            success:function(response){
                if(response=="login_success"){
                    $("#login_email").css("background-color","green");;
                    $("#login_password").css("background-color","green");;
                }
                if(response=="login_failed"){
                    $("#login_email").css("background-color","red");;
                    $("#login_password").css("background-color","red");;
                }
            }
        });
        return false
    })
});
```

And HTML:

```
<form name="signIn" id="signIn" name="signIn" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" id="login_email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="********" maxlength="20" id="login_password" />
    <input type="image" id="signInButton" src="img/signIn.png" alt=">" name="submit" />
</form>
```